# Merchant of Venice "I'll die for't a women had the ring" (Shakespeare, 5.1, 221)

Tags: literature, pun

Portia has the ring but Bassanio believes that he had given the ring to a male. Portia says "I'll die for't a women had the ring"(Shakespeare, 5.1, 221), which is funny as it really is a women who has the ring. I do not think this is a pun, as the line itself is not funny, rather its the situation the line is used in. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: A pun is a kind of play on words, and I don't see any play on words here, so it is not a pun (as far as I am aware). Wh do you think it might be one?

Comment: The fact that there is no play on words was what confused me. As I find the line quite comedic is my reason to believe it is a pun. But now that I think about it I believe that it would be situational irony.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this [literature.se] question doesn't really have any relevance to learning English.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. It is not a pun in the common sense of the word. The verse goes:

> If you had known the virtue of the ring,
> Or half her worthiness that gave the ring,
> Or your own honor to contain the ring,
> You would not then have parted with the ring.
> What man is there so much unreasonable,
> If you had pleased to have defended it
> With any terms of zeal, wanted the modesty
> To urge the thing held as a ceremony?
> Nerissa teaches me what to believe.
> **I’ll die for ’t but some woman had the ring.**

Portia here in this verse appears upset over Bassanio's claim that he has given away the ring and refuses to believe it was a woman whom the ring was given to. The key word is "but".

> I'll die for it but (if it is not the case that) some woman had the ring

Portia is basically saying to her husband: "I bet it is some woman whom you gave the ring to. And I am wagering my life on it."

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You cleared my confusion towards if it is a pun or not. Now that I understand it a bit more, I think it would be situational irony. Does that fit the quote.

Comment: @Kash I wouldn't call it ironic. But it is a nuanced line and could elicit different interpretations. My reading is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. I would call this situation teasing because of how she tries to play with Bassanio's feelings.
**

- The reason why
  Portia is trying to tease Bassanio from the above dialogue. Portia was initially insisting that Bassanio wanted to give the ring to a woman and wagering her life on it and she says ‘I’ll die for’t, but some woman had the ring’. When Bassanio mentions that ‘The ring of me to give the worthy doctor’, Portia mentions that ‘I’ll have that doctor for my bedfellow’ . Portia is saying that since Bassanio gave the ring to Balthazar, she would rather be his wife than Bassanio because Balthazar had the ring. However, Portia already knows that she is Balthazar and she is purposely trying to tease Bassanio. Hence, I feel that Portia is trying to tease Bassanio.

**

Comment: Why the non-existing footnote? Forgot something? :)

Comment: Whoops sorry I am new to this website and I am not sure what you are talking about